# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi connection fails

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I am not succeeding to connect to wifi anymore.

If have tried:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 down
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
```

I have:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V [8086:15a3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V [17aa:2227]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e


sudo lshw -class network
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 59
   serial: 60:57:18:ce:45:eb
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-72-generic firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:54 memory:f1100000-f1101fff

sudo iwconfig
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Domaine Resident"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: BC:F6:85:E9:00:A0   
      Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:16   Missed beacon:0
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT

As advised I did

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

With at the same time::

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4358] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4359] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4455] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4462] device (br-91c4c7333196): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed nm-dispatcher: req:3 'up' [docker0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed nm-dispatcher: req:3 'up' [docker0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4577] device (br-91c4c7333196): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4583] device (br-b74dd43c01c0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed nm-dispatcher: req:4 'up' [br-91c4c7333196]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.4677] device (br-b74dd43c01c0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed nm-dispatcher: req:5 'up' [br-b74dd43c01c0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp4s0 flags: No such device
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed nm-dispatcher: req:4 'up' [br-91c4c7333196]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-7IO_Yw/glib2.0-2.48.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2635: instance '0x4aa6460' has no handler with id '281743'
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed kernel: [32251.817537] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.5311] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760137.5312] device (wlp4s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: ** (gnome-shell:2771): CRITICAL **: nma_mobile_providers_database_lookup_cdma_sid: assertion 'sid > 0' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_text_get_editable: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_text_get_text: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_text_set_text: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_text_get_editable: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_text_get_text: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (gnome-shell:2771): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_text_set_text: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed nm-dispatcher: req:5 'up' [br-b74dd43c01c0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:37 nodyahed systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: (deja-dup-monitor:3416): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 3479 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2404] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2527] policy: auto-activating connection 'Domaine Resident'
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2535] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Domaine Resident' (0553371f-b223-4aa8-a4f6-20c7ed81c10c)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2537] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2539] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2545] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2547] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Domaine Resident' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2548] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2582] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2585] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2586] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Domaine Resident' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2587] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Domaine Resident'
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2587] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2587] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2587] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2587] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.2798] sup-iface[0x20aa950,wlp4s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (SSID='Domaine Resident' freq=2422 MHz)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.626135] wlp4s0: authenticate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.631551] wlp4s0: send auth to bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3474] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (SSID='Domaine Resident' freq=2422 MHz)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.634675] wlp4s0: authenticated
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3543] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.638092] wlp4s0: associate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.641764] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=5)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: Associated with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.643565] wlp4s0: associated
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.643615] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3632] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3757] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3963] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3964] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Domaine Resident'.
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3965] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3975] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760138.3988] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): dhclient started with pid 6575
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed kernel: [32252.696339] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0
Apr 21 09:35:38 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.110.172 on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3ff1500a)
Apr 21 09:35:39 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::5e80:6ef9:e367:7b88.
Apr 21 09:35:39 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: New relevant interface wlp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 21 09:35:39 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Registering new address record for fe80::5e80:6ef9:e367:7b88 on wlp4s0.*.
Apr 21 09:35:41 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.110.172 on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3ff1500a)
Apr 21 09:35:47 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760147.1877] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 21 09:35:47 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760147.1883] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Apr 21 09:35:48 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.110.172 on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3ff1500a)
Apr 21 09:36:03 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe5363330)
Apr 21 09:36:06 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe5363330)
Apr 21 09:36:09 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xe5363330)
Apr 21 09:36:17 nodyahed dhclient[6575]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0xe5363330)
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <warn>  [1492760183.1867] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): request timed out
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.1867] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2029] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 6575
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2029] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed timeout -> done
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2033] device (wlp4s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2035] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2040] manager: startup complete
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <warn>  [1492760183.2048] device (wlp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Domaine Resident'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2081] device (wlp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::5e80:6ef9:e367:7b88 on wlp4s0.
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::5e80:6ef9:e367:7b88.
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Interface wlp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed kernel: [32297.497415] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed gnome-session[2587]: message repeated 2 times: [ Gjs-Message: JS LOG: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <warn>  [1492760183.2782] sup-iface[0x20aa950,wlp4s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2783] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2794] policy: auto-activating connection 'Domaine Resident'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2805] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Domaine Resident' (0553371f-b223-4aa8-a4f6-20c7ed81c10c)
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2806] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2807] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2811] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2813] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Domaine Resident' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2813] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2847] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2852] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2855] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Domaine Resident' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2855] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Domaine Resident'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2855] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2856] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2856] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.2856] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Apr 21 09:36:23 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760183.3214] sup-iface[0x20aa950,wlp4s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (SSID='Domaine Resident' freq=2422 MHz)
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.433871] wlp4s0: authenticate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.439847] wlp4s0: send auth to bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.1575] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (SSID='Domaine Resident' freq=2422 MHz)
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.444751] wlp4s0: authenticated
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.446538] wlp4s0: associate with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (try 1/3)
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.451228] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=5)
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.1695] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: Associated with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.461579] wlp4s0: associated
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.1806] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed kernel: [32298.469102] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.1905] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to bc:f6:85:e9:00:a0 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.2114] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.2114] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Domaine Resident'.
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.2115] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.2119] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed NetworkManager[6363]: <info>  [1492760184.2135] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): dhclient started with pid 6608
Apr 21 09:36:24 nodyahed dhclient[6608]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.110.172 on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x688432cd)
Apr 21 09:36:25 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::5e80:6ef9:e367:7b88.
Apr 21 09:36:25 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: New relevant interface wlp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 21 09:36:25 nodyahed avahi-daemon[1001]: Registering new address record for fe80::5e80:6ef9:e367:7b88 on wlp4s0.*.
Apr 21 09:36:27 nodyahed dhclient[6608]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.110.172 on wlp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x688432cd)
```

Edit

I ran the Wireless Info Script from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and put the result [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24446619/)

Comment: did you try:: $ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop $ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start With at the same time:: $ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog ...